# What happens if I don't use any MongoDB Package for Laravel?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a Laravel Project with MongoDB & I don't want to use any package for MongoDB. I want to write MongoDB Codes regularly like :

```
<?php
    $m = new MongoClient();
    echo "Connection to database successfully";
    $db = $m->mydb;
    echo "Database mydb selected";
?>
```

I had some questions :

1. If I don't use any package I need change CONFIG in Laravel Files ?
2. What happens to AUTH ? It works or not by using MongoDB or I should make Some Changes ?

Thanks ...

Comment: Have you tried to change?

Comment: @SougataBose Change what ?

Comment: To change the config and implement your regular codes?

Comment: @SougataBose No, I'm begginer to MongoDB & Laravel & I don't know how to change configs for MongoDB in Laravel ...